# How to encode and decode electromagnetic waves in binary?

Tags: wave, binary, electromagnetic

If I am not wrong the electromagnetic waves can be produced by opening and closing an electric circuit. (Tell me if I am wrong)

Let's say we want to send an electromagnetic wave that has the message of letter 'a'. In binary the letter 'a' is '01100001'. To produce that electromagnetic wave I would have to open close close open open open open close the circuit in this order to make that binary number.  (Again: Tell me if I am wrong cuz I am totally a newbie to this stuff)

My question is: How could I decode this message to letter 'a' again so that it's useful?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent amplitude modulated radio?

Comment: Don't know what that is o.O

Comment: How about AM radio? Sounds more familiar?

Comment: @Samuel can you kindly explain a little instead of closing my question? At least try to help. I am new to these kind of things! :(

Comment: @Samuel Ok now it makes a little bit sense. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: I'm not downvoting or closing your question. I can see why someone would though. You're *so* new that you need to do a lot of reading on your own first. You question is so high level that the proper response is equally high level: build an electromagnetic wave receiver and a decoder. Which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Please try and explain the encoding and decoding in a nutshell it wouldn't take you long! Just write a quick answer dude!

Comment: Some of us know how all these things work to some degree, so please don't group us into that statement.

Comment: @Samuel Nope that doesn't include you :)

Comment: An early way to transmit data over radio was to use Morse Code - the transmitter was turned on and off in various patterns which represented letters and numbers.  Look up "Morse Code" in Wikipedia for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is called [OOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying) (On-Off Keying). It's a simple form of AM radio communication.

Decoding is done as the reverse of encoding, the level of the received signal is detected at the same frequency the data is encoded, those detected levels represent the bits in the encoded binary data.

Comment: Can I ask, which materials are used to detect these waves so accurately and afterwards decode them into some useful information?

Comment: Can I build a reciever myself? I mean at home. Or do I need (let me guess) a factory?

Comment: The material is electrically conductive, like metal, copper works. The device is called an antenna. You can make one out of copper wire.

Comment: One can be build by oneself, at home. I don't know your skill level with such things.

Comment: I think I know how to work with copper works and conductors and electromagnets etc. can you explain a little bit. Just a little bit about how the antenna works? Please!!!

Comment: Google for "crystal radio receiver" to find lots of information on an early form of receiver.

Comment: *Dude*, you have all the keywords you need to do some reading on your own. Go read the Wikipedia page for [antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)) then come back and ask about what you don't understand.

Comment: Also, go look up Morse Code.